# Generate normal distributed random numbers in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, random, numbers, normal-distribution

I want to generate a vector of n normal-distributed random variables in C++.  In Matlab you can do this with the command "randn(n)", but I haven't found any similar method.
With best regards
Patsch

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution

Comment: [Box Muller Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform)

Answer (score 2):

If you use C++11 or later, there is [std::normal_distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/)